# Real-life usage of Path.relativize() if source path contains anything else than real folders

Tags: java, filesystems, java-7, nio

While preparing a java 7 certification exam, I had to start looking closely at the `Path.relativize()` method. While superficially its purpose seems straight forward, express a path relatively to another, I have found that its implementation defies all understanding I had of filesystems, namely on Windows or Linux/Unix.
Consider the following:

```
// Case 1
System.out.println(Paths.get("c:\\folder1\\folder2").relativize(Paths.get("c:\\file.txt")));

// Case 2
System.out.println(Paths.get("c:\\folder1\\folder2\\other-file.txt").relativize(Paths.get("c:\\file.txt")));

// Case 3
System.out.println(Paths.get("c:\\folder1\\..\\.\\folder1\\..\\.\\folder1\\..\\.\\folder1\\..").relativize(Paths.get("c:\\file.txt")));
```

The output I got is:

```
..\..\file.txt
..\..\..\file.txt
..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\file.txt
```

Case 1 illustrates the straight forward usage one could expect of that function, i.e. find the path of a file relatively to a folder, given the absolute paths of both file and folder. Fine, that gives me something I can type in a cmd window in Windows and will find my file correctly.
Case 2, as discussed in other StackOverflow questions, highlights the fact that the method has no way of distinguishing a file name from a folder name (a folder can contain a . in its name, and a file can have none). OK, to me this should mean the method should come with the caveat: "use at your own risk, if providing a path where the leaf is a file, the relativized result won't work in a file system". Or does it, if yes, which file system?
Case 3 to me is nonsense. The method does not even take into account the meaning of "." and ".." in the source path, but happily uses ".." in the result as a way to go up a level in the source folder. This may make sense in a theoretical filesystem I'm yet to encounter, but in Windows, Linux or Unix, the result is unusable. "..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\file.txt" will of course not point to file.txt relatively to a path that despite being expressed as "c:\folder1\..\.\folder1\..\.\folder1\..\.\folder1\.." really points to "c:\".

Thanks for hanging in so far. The question: what possible use could one make of the Path.relativize() method considering its results only make real-life sense in a fraction of cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression

```
Paths.get("c:\\folder1\\..\\.\\folder1\\..\\.\\folder1\\..\\.\\folder1\\..")
```

is really just `c:\` when normalized.

If you then relativize `c:\file.txt` against that path, you get a relative path that will lead you there. From `c:\`, that relative path is `file.txt`.

The result

```
..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\file.txt
```

is exactly equivalent to `file.txt`. When normalized, leading `..` will be discarded. I agree it isn't pretty, but that's just an implementation detail.

---

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The "normalization" bit is what escapes me. If I was to type "dir c:\folder1\..\.\folder1\..\.\folder1\..\.\\folder1\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\file.txt" in a cmd window in Windows, I would not find file.txt. This is why I am questioning the purpose of a real-filesystem-like syntax applied to real-life paths which doesn't work in real life. If the syntax was something like {back-11}\\file.txt, then I'd get it: it would be a proprietary way to express one Java path compared to another. But the syntax suggests otherwise. What is this normalization useful for?

Comment: @NotSoOldNick `Path` has a `normalize` method. Check it out for more details, ie. `..` and `.` . It basically removes redundant elements. Obviously, that path isn't a directory so `dir` wouldn't work. But if you tried to copy it (or whatever), it should work and find `C:\file.txt`.

Comment: Thanks, I finally get it! So in order to obtain filesystem-usable output, a path that is going to be the source path in the `relativize()` method should always get normalized first.

Comment: @NotSoOldNick The `relativize()` is more for human readable output. I believe that if you use it with any method that does actual file system IO, it will be converted appropriately, either by Java or by the file system. I don't know the implementation.